# SQL SUM COLUMN FROM A SAME TABLE AND Multi ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table...

Is there any way to get the sum associated with id 1?

The final result should be... 4300.

[Question Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8leV.jpg)

===============================================

I got an answer using WITH in query which is a good answer.

But since I'm using mysql 5.7 that doesn't support WITH query yet.

So I want a query method that is similar to WITH .

This is the response I got from Zaki.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b105bbb048c2e9f8c33fcbf79d27660)

Sorry for my language.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Recursive CTE or iterative stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to get all the linked users:

```
with recursive u as
(select t.id, t.`Referral id`, t.Balance from yourtable t where id = 1
union
select t.id, t.`Referral id`, t.Balance from u inner join yourtable t
on u.id = t.`Referral id`)
(select sum(Balance) from u)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b105bbb048c2e9f8c33fcbf79d27660)